# Bibtex to HTML/Markdown/etc., using Pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, conversion, html, pandoc, markdown

It seems that [`Pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is capable of dealing with references given in a `.bib` file. Yet, I haven't been able to simply ask `Pandoc` to convert a `.bib` file into `html`, `markdown` or other formats. Is there a way to do so?

As an example of what I mean (since I am not sure I am clear enough...), I would say the following to export `myfile.bib` to `myfile.pdf`: Create `myfile.tex` which contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} % or another bibliography style!
\bibliography{myfile.bib}
\end{document}
```

and compile it using `pdflatex` and `bibtex`.

Is there such a simple way to export `myfile.bib` to (say) `myfile.html`?

Comment: I think the accepted these day should be the one by @AlexanderVonMoll.  I.e. as of version 0.4 (Aug 2014), this functionality is built in to pandoc-citeproc.

Comment: Both answers are quite similar I guess: One uses a tex file as input, the other one a markdown file. But both work equally well!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`pandoc` cannot convert a `.bib` file into another file format<sup>1</sup>. However, it can convert a `.tex` file which contains references (called from a `.bib` file) into a pdf, odt, html, ... If your `.tex` file just contains the `\nocite{*}` command, the result is similar (you will have all your references printed).

Here is the magic command:

```
pandoc test.tex -o output.odt --bibliography /my/bibliography.bib
```

or (for pdf)

```
pandoc test.tex -o output.pdf --bibliography /my/bibliography.bib
```

or (for html)

```
pandoc test.tex -o output.html --bibliography /my/bibliography.bib
```

Note that several launches of the pandoc command could be necessary to obtain a correct result.

## MWE

### Files

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{author00:_title}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib` file:

```
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
```

### Outputs

**Pdf**

[image]

**html**

html generated by `pandoc test.tex  -o output.html --bibliography mybib.bib`:

```js
<p><span class="citation">(Author 2000)</span></p>
<div class="references">
<p>Author. 2000. <em>Title</em>. Publisher.</p>
</div>
```

---

<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8lDf.png)</sup> The [documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) is not very clear about this point. Some phrasings could lead one to believe it's possible to directly convert from .bib to .*. I tested it and it isn't working. You have to use a .tex file if you want to convert a .bib file (today).

Answer (score 24):

As of [pandoc-citeproc-0.4](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-citeproc-0.4/changelog) `pandoc-citeproc` has support for a  `\nocite{*}`-equivalent.

`mybib.bib` file:

```
@article{behbahani2014aircraft,
    title={Aircraft Integration Challenges and Opportunities for Distributed Intelligent Control, Power, Thermal Management, Diagnostic and Prognostic Systems},
    author={Behbahani, Alireza R and Von Moll, Alexander and Zeller, Robert and Ordo, James},
    journal={SAE Tech. Pap. 2014-01},
    volume={2161},
    year={2014}
  }
@article{jia2013emergence,
    title={Emergence of bimodality in controlling complex networks},
    author={Jia, Tao and Liu, Yang-Yu and Cs{\'o}ka, Endre and P{\'o}sfai, M{\'a}rton and Slotine, Jean-Jacques and Barab{\'a}si, Albert-L{\'a}szl{\'o}},
    journal={Nature communications},
    volume={4},
    year={2013},
    publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
 }

@article{zhu2015game,
    title={Game-theoretic methods for robustness, security, and resilience of cyberphysical control systems: games-in-games principle for optimal cross-layer resilient control systems},
    author={Zhu, Quanyan and Basar, Tamer},
    journal={Control Systems, IEEE},
    volume={35},
    number={1},
    pages={46--65},
    year={2015},
    publisher={IEEE}
 }
@inproceedings{rieger2013hierarchical,
    title={A hierarchical multi-agent dynamical system architecture for resilient control systems},
    author={Rieger, Craig and Zhu, Quanyan},
    booktitle={Resilient Control Systems (ISRCS), 2013 6th International Symposium on},
    pages={6--12},
    year={2013},
    organization={IEEE}
  }
```

Along with the following Markdown skeleton `mybib.md`:

```
---
bibliography: mybib.bib
nocite: '@*'
...

# Bibliography
```

Built using `pandoc --filter=pandoc-citeproc --standalone mybib.md -o mybib.html`

Produces the following output:
[image]

---

The HTML that corresponds with this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="bibliography" class="unnumbered">Bibliography</h1>
<div id="refs" class="references">
<div id="ref-behbahani2014aircraft">
<p>Behbahani, Alireza R, Alexander Von Moll, Robert Zeller, and James Ordo. 2014. “Aircraft Integration Challenges and Opportunities for Distributed     Intelligent Control, Power, Thermal Management, Diagnostic and Prognostic Systems.” <em>SAE Tech. Pap. 2014-01</em> 2161.</p>
</div>
<div id="ref-jia2013emergence">
<p>Jia, Tao, Yang-Yu Liu, Endre Csóka, Márton Pósfai, Jean-Jacques Slotine, and Albert-László Barabási. 2013. “Emergence of Bimodality in Controlling Complex Networks.” <em>Nature Communications</em> 4. Nature Publishing Group.            </p>
</div>
<div id="ref-rieger2013hierarchical">
<p>Rieger, Craig, and Quanyan Zhu. 2013. “A Hierarchical Multi-Agent Dynamical System Architecture for Resilient Control Systems.” In <em>Resilient Control Systems (ISRCS), 2013 6th International Symposium on</em>, 6–12. IEEE.</p>
</div>
<div id="ref-zhu2015game">
<p>Zhu, Quanyan, and Tamer Basar. 2015. “Game-Theoretic Methods for Robustness, Security, and Resilience of Cyberphysical Control Systems: Games-in-Games Principle for Optimal Cross-Layer Resilient Control Systems.” <em>Control Systems, IEEE</em> 35 (1). IEEE: 46–65.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I consistently get this error: `pandoc-citeproc: Error in $: expected product (:*:), encountered Object`

Comment: Which versions of pandoc and pandoc-citeproc are you using? Do you have your own (non) working example or were you working with the example I provided?

Comment: Works for me. Using `pandoc-citeproc         0.10.5.1-1build4` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic