# With pandoc, is it possible to export a bibliography in markdown?

Tags: bibtex, pandoc, markdown

I have a document with a bibliography in BibTeX and must to some post-treatment on the generated bibliography before producing the final document (I must emphasize some author names and sort the biography in some non-obvious way). I thought I could generate the text of the bibliography in markdown and deal with it from that point.

I tried to adapt what was proposed in another question ([Bibtex to html/Markdown/etc., using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/bibtex-to-html-markdown-etc-using-pandoc)) :

```
pandoc --filter=pandoc-citeproc --standalone mybib.md -o mybib-out.md
```

with a `mybib.md` containing the following:

```
---
bibliography: 'mybib.bib'
nocite: '@*'
...

Bibliography
============
```

but the output file only contains basically the same as the input, while exporting to pdf or html generates the actual bibliography.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a different markdown format, e.g:

`pandoc -t markdown_strict --filter=pandoc-citeproc --standalone mybib.md -o mybib-out.md`

The formats are listed in [pandoc's documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options).
The default setting is pandoc's markdown which might not generate the bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc-citeproc doesn't insert the references in Markdown unless you explicitly specify a div with ID `refs`:

```
---
bibliography: 'mybib.bib'
nocite: '@*'
...

Bibliography
============

::: {#refs}
:::
```

Alternatively, one can also disable the citations extension in the output format, which will cause pandoc to insert the expanded citations:

```
pandoc --to=markdown-citations …
```