# is there a command line (or on-line) conversion tool bibtex to markdown (for large bibtex files)

Tags: bibtex, conversion, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I have a few thousand bibtex entries that I want formatted in, say, acm format in a markdown format.

On-line tools like https://balanceofcowards.net/bibtex2pdf.html  just crash on my input file.

http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~wbl/biblio/tools/bib2txt.bat needs utilities I don't have locally (e.g. dvi2tty) which is odd since I already have a local tex installation

https://github.com/ledlie/cmd-line-tools/blob/master/bib2txt is cool but it does not generate output in some officially approved style

I tried hacking something in `pandoc` using instructions from [Bibtex to html/Markdown/etc., using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/bibtex-to-html-markdown-etc-using-pandoc/) i.e.   grep the bibtex for the tags,   create a faux .tex file with references to all those tags, then do

```
pandoc aa.tex -o aa.md --bibliography aa.bib
```

Expected result: a markdown files with links to the bib content

Actual results: I got was the links  (no actually ref content)

```
[@fugrid16] [@mirirli11] [@Kim:2015] [@turhan2009relative]
```

Answer (score 2):

With pandoc you must specify a csl file (with the option `--csl=file.csl`) which describe how to format the bibliography. You can find a csl file at the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) e. g. [Association for Computing Machinery](https://www.zotero.org/styles/association-for-computing-machinery).

It seems that you can note generate a markdown file but you can do somethings like :

```
pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc aa.tex --bibliography=aa.bib --csl=association-for-computing-machinery.csl -o aa.html
```